# What "Name" parameter must I specify to remove an IIS custom error using Remove-WebConfigurationProperty in Powershell?

Tags: iis, powershell

Trying to use Powershell to script the removal of specific custom errors from an IIS website.

I have got this far:

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter "/system.webServer/httpErrors/error[@statusCode='403' and @subStatusCode='4']" -Location IIS:\Sites\www.mysite.com
```

but running that fails with a warning that:

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty string.
```

I have no idea what to specify for the `Name` parameter here - and Remove-WebConfigurationProperty is woefully underdocumented... any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah... cracked it. It's not Remove-WebConfigurationProperty, it's Clear-WebConfiguration that's used in this context:

```
Clear-WebConfiguration -Filter "/system.webServer/httpErrors/error[@statusCode='403' and @subStatusCode='4']" -Location IIS:\Sites\www.mysite.com
```

Comment: Note that this removes an entire XML element. (That appears to be what you want, but users hoping to remove an *attribute* with `Remove-WebConfigurationProperty` may find their way here.)